# Sant Dnyaneshwar

Tags: vedas, sanskrit, saint

[Sant Dnyaneshwar](https://www.google.com/search?gs_ssp=eJzj4tLP1TdILqowMSwzYPQSK07MK1FIyatMzEstzihPLFLIzS_LTAUA1uoMgw&q=sant%20dnyaneshwar%20movie&oq=Sant%20&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j46i39j46i433i512l2j46i512j0i512l2j46i512.2093j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung-ss&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Can Saints perform miracles in the 21st century similar to performed by Sant Dnyaneshwar in the 13th century?

Comment: Jñāneśvara was glorified too as he was a saint for a huge population. Often devotional leaders have been glorified and shown divine in the medieval period by the populace. That is how folk appeal worked.